# Выбрать максимальное и минимальное значение по модулю из массива

Tags: javascript

Задача: Найти максимальный/минимальный по модулю элемент массива.
Нагуглил только Math.abs, но не понял как применить, подскажите. Еще очень хочу услышать критику кода от опытных программистов.

```
function mission(){
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 200, -210, -10000, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -100];

var numbersPositive = numbers.filter(function findPositive(numbers){return numbers >= 0});
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math,numbersPositive); // Максимальное число 

var numbersNegative = numbers.filter(function findNegative(numbers){return numbers < 0});
var minValue = Math.min.apply(Math,numbersNegative); // Минимальное число 


document.getElementById('text').value = 'Массив чисел: ' + numbers + '\n' + '\n' + 
'Числа с положительным значением из массива: ' + numbersPositive + ' ' +  'Всего: ' + numbersPositive.length + '\n' + 
'Числа с отрицательным значением из массива: ' + numbersNegative + ' ' +  'Всего: ' + numbersNegative.length + '\n' + '\n' + 
'Максимальное число в массиве: ' + maxValue + '\n' + 'Минимальное число: ' + minValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно как-то так попробовать.

```
function mission() {
    var numbers = [<тут входные данные>],
        absNumbers = numbers.map(Math.abs),
        minValue = Math.min.apply(Math, absNumbers),
        maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, absNumbers);
   <тут вывод результатов>    
}
```

Comment: Господи, как же все оказалось просто. Спасибо большое

Comment: Не за что ) Тут главное просто сам принцип понять.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [267, 306, 108];
var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, array); // 306
```

Comment: обратите внимание на условие "Найти максимальный/минимальный по модулю"